# Trying to add image to pdf using jsPDF

Tags: javascript, node.js, jspdf

Trying this code

> pdfGenerate.js

```
generatePDF = function() {
var imgData = 'D:/work/TiffImages/png/895153.0000.png';
var doc = new jsPDF('p', 'pt', 'a4');
doc.text(20, 20, 'CTS Aarchival');
doc.addImage(imgData, 'PNG', 15, 40, 180, 180);
doc.save('CTStest.pdf');    }
```

**Error:**

```
Uncaught TypeError: doc.addImage is not a function
```

In HTML I am just calling this method onclick()
And all required js files are included.

Comment: [Problems with addImage](https://github.com/MrRio/jsPDF/issues/545). Which file are you importing?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Simple solution:**

Instead of using **jsPDF.js** library use **jsPDF.debug.js** , it includes all the modules which we need.

Answer (score 4):

`addImage` function is in another module called **drumroll please** `addImage`. So if you're importing the `jsPdf.js` it doens't contain that module.

Here is the doc [link](https://rawgit.com/MrRio/jsPDF/master/docs/module-addImage.html#~addImage). Also check out these github issues [here](https://github.com/MrRio/jsPDF/issues/783) and [here](https://github.com/MrRio/jsPDF/issues/545)

Answer (score 3):

You can also do it in this way:

```
var pdf = new jsPDF();
var img = new Image;
img.onload = function() {
    pdf.addImage(this, 10, 10);
    pdf.save("CTStest.pdf");
    };
img.crossOrigin = "";  

img.src = 'D:/work/TiffImages/png/895153.0000.png';
```

Comment: While trying this I am getting this error: "Not allowed to load local resource: file:///D:/work/TiffImages/png/895153.0000.png"